# Access data by variable JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, xhtml, icefaces

I have an xhtml file, with a backing bean, i'd like to create a table dynamically. I'm able to create the columns dynamically, but how can i acces the **item** variable's **heading** property. I mean, if there is the "Stock" string in the **headings** variable (so this will be the heading of the columns), than how can I acces the **item.stock** data?

XHTML:

```
            <ice:dataTable value="#{tableBean.carInventory}" var="item">                    
                <ice:columns value="#{tableBean.showableCols}" var="headings">                                        
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{headings}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <ice:outputText value="#{item.?????headings??????}"/>
                </ice:columns>
            </ice:dataTable>
```

Comment: Have you tried `#{item[headings]}`?

Comment: yeah that was the solution, thank you very much

Comment: you're welcome. There is [wiki here at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) for this kind of expression. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I can't accept a comment, so i have to write one, the answer is using: `#{item[headings]}`, thanks to **eljunior**